# Problems with nested sapply for batch extracting excel sheets and combining in one dataset

Tags: r, excel, loops, nested, sapply

I have a specific set of sheets (see `name_sheet`) from a set of excel files (`file.names`) that I need to extract in order to generate a database by sheet.

I am having problems with the `sapply` function as I need to repeat the code in section C for each sheet. I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Cannot find the sheet you requested in the file!
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
# A: Create data set of sheet names and indexes
name_sheet <- rbind.data.frame(c("EXTRAC.N°01", 1), 
                              c("PREC.FRES 12", 13), 
                              c("PREC.SALPR 13", 14),
                              c("PREC.SECO 14", 15), 
                              c("CUADRO Nº 17 Y HABLADO 02", 18),
                              c("DESEMB.N°05 HABLADO-01-03-05", 20),
                              c("CUADRO Nº 15 (2)", 21))

colnames(name_sheet) <- c("name","index")

# B: Read all excel files into a list
file.names <- list.files(here("data"), pattern = "ANUAL", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

# C: Read each of the selected sheets by file and append them by sheet

for (i in nrow(name_sheet)) {
df.list[i] <- lapply(file.names, 
                  read.xlsx, 
                  sheetIndex = name_sheet$index[i],
                  header = TRUE)

# Combine in one dataset
  df_[i] <- smartbind(list = df.list[i], fill = " ")

# Write to disk
  write.xlsx(df_[i], here("Data", "Consumo_Humano.xlsx"), 
           sheetName = name_sheet$name[i], 
           row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: the error message suggests to check the sheet number / index : you could try to debug by testing on `head(names_sheet,n=1)` and then increase `n` until you find the file / sheet causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I did not found any problem using the proposed test.

Comment: If it works for all n, there's no problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there were several errors in the code:

1. @X Æ A-12 was right I was not using openxlsx, and therefore now I have used its functions (loadWorkbook, addWorksheet, etc.).
2. The loop did not have the correct sequence: `nrow(name_sheet)`

Secondly, as consequence of using openxlsx, you need to create a workbook first and then start to create sheets. Hence the final code is:

```
    #Generate list of sheets and positions
    name_sheet <- rbind.data.frame(c("EXTRAC.N°01", 1), 
                                  c("PREC.FRES 12", 13), 
                                  c("PREC.SALPR 13", 14),
                                  c("PREC.SECO 14", 15), 
                                  c("CUADRO Nº 17", 18),
                                  c("DESEMB.N°05 (2)", 20),
                                  c("CUADRO Nº 15 (2)", 21))
    
    colnames(name_sheet) <- c("name","index")
    
    # Read all excel files into a list
    file.names <- list.files(here("data"), 
                             pattern = "ANUAL", 
                             full.names = TRUE, 
                             recursive = TRUE)
    
    #Read each of the selected sheets by file and joint them
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(name_sheet)) {
    df.list <- lapply(file.names, 
                      read.xlsx, 
                      sheet = name_sheet$name[i],
                      colNames = TRUE,
                      skipEmptyRows = TRUE,
                      check.names = TRUE,
                      fillMergedCells = FALSE,
                      )
    
    # Combine in one dataset
    
    df <- smartbind(list = df.list, fill = "")
    
    # Load workbook and write to disk
    
    wb <- loadWorkbook(file = here("Data", "Consumo_Humano.xlsx"))
    
    sheet <- name_sheet$name[i]
    
    # Add sheets
    
    addWorksheet(wb,
      sheetName = sheet,
      header = c("ODD HEAD LEFT", "ODD HEAD CENTER", "ODD HEAD RIGHT"),
      footer = c("ODD FOOT RIGHT", "ODD FOOT CENTER", "ODD FOOT RIGHT")
    )
    
    writeData(wb, sheet = sheet, x = df, colNames = T, rowNames = F)
    
    saveWorkbook(wb,
      file = here("Data", "Consumo_Humano.xlsx"),
      overwrite = TRUE
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from the information provided but I assume that you are using `openxlsx`. If possible `readr::read_xlsx` permits you to specift sheet names which might be a possibiliy in your use case.

You might be have an easier time with `purrr::map_df` where you can read in your data in a list similar to what you have above but then also bind rows into a single data frame within the same call.